# Multiple Flat Surface Shader Animations on One Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, mesh

I am using a mesh animation on canvas called Flat Surface Shader, here's the [github](https://github.com/wagerfield/flat-surface-shader):

I basically use 2 js files, which finds the div id="surface" and puts the animation in there.

It works great but i want to duplicate it on the different parts in html. And use them as a section seperator header background.

Tips:

1. I think I should either run something like initialize() fuction for every different div id. But couldn't make it work.
2. Or maybe I can do something here in the js file?

Global Properties

```
var now, start = Date.now();    
var center = FSS.Vector3.create();    
var attractor = FSS.Vector3.create();


var surface = document.getElementById('home');    
var output = document.getElementById('surface');    
var renderer, scene, mesh, geometry, material;    
var canvasRenderer;    
var gui, autopilotController;
```